# Simple Quarkus Kogito project fails to build - several ambiguous and unsatisfied dependencies

Tags: quarkus, kogito

I have a very simple project where I'm experimenting with BPM (Quarkus, Kogito, jBPM and Drools) and it fails to build on Java 11. Here is the github repo: https://github.com/JoaoCamposFrom94/bpmdemo/tree/2808d87428ddb91c43c0b2554a5808ca4299293e

The project has a couple of REST endpoints that save forms in a hashmap.
I was going to experiment with drools by using it to validate some fields on the endpoint POST /demo/form/{id} and with jBPM by starting a simple process that executes arbitrary java code on the endpoint POST /demo/form.

By running `mvn compile quarkus:dev` I get an error in some generated code.

```java
import org.kie.kogito.Config;

@javax.inject.Singleton()
public class Application implements org.kie.kogito.Application {

    @org.eclipse.microprofile.config.inject.ConfigProperty(name = "kogito.service.url", defaultValue = "")
    java.lang.String kogitoService;

    @javax.inject.Inject()
    org.kie.kogito.Config config;

    public Config config() {
        return config;
    }
}
...
(class changed for brevity)
```

```sh
11:16:28,528 ERROR [io.qua.dev.DevModeMain] Failed to start Quarkus: java.lang.RuntimeException: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
        [error]: Build step io.quarkus.arc.deployment.ArcProcessor#validate threw an exception: javax.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: Found 4 deployment problems: 
[1] Ambiguous dependencies for type org.kie.kogito.Application and qualifiers [@Default]
        - java member: com.demo.form.CreateFormProcessResource#application
        - declared on CLASS bean [types=[com.demo.form.CreateFormProcessResource], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=com.demo.form.CreateFormProcessResource]
        - available beans:
                - CLASS bean [types=[org.kie.kogito.app.Application, java.lang.Object, org.kie.kogito.Application], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=org.kie.kogito.app.Application]
                - CLASS bean [types=[com.demo.poc.Application, java.lang.Object, org.kie.kogito.Application], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=com.demo.poc.Application]
[2] Ambiguous dependencies for type org.kie.kogito.Config and qualifiers [@Default]
        - java member: org.kie.kogito.app.Application#config
        - declared on CLASS bean [types=[org.kie.kogito.app.Application, java.lang.Object, org.kie.kogito.Application], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=org.kie.kogito.app.Application]
        - available beans:
                - CLASS bean [types=[com.demo.poc.ApplicationConfig, org.kie.kogito.Config, java.lang.Object], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=com.demo.poc.ApplicationConfig]
                - CLASS bean [types=[org.kie.kogito.Config, java.lang.Object, org.kie.kogito.app.ApplicationConfig], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=org.kie.kogito.app.ApplicationConfig]
```

Complete dump of the error message: https://pastebin.com/dLDwaWfJ

Answer (score 3):

This got answered at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kogito-development/Xkkon4tLHdo.

My pom.xml was specifying a kogito build plugin and a quarkus build plugin. Having both causes conflicts, I simply removed the kogito build plugin.